# AndroidManifest.xml with multiple application tags

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest, manifest

I'm very new to Android programming and I've been trying to figure out why my app is force-closing on a button-click. I've narrowed it down to a few things.

One question; Is it possible to have more than one `<application>` tag in the manifest xml?

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.dummies.android.beergoggles"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Result" android:label="@string/app_name">        </activity>
</application>
<application android:name="MyApp" 
   android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
   android:label="@string/app_name2"></application>
```

I've been researching, but found only a vague post about creating a new manifest file for a new application. The MyApp application is just an app for a "global variable", since I guess there's no way to do that without a new application.

Here is the code for MyApp in case it helps:

```
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApp extends Application{

public static int resultCount;

public int getCount(){
    return resultCount;
  }
public void setCount(int c){
    resultCount = c;
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: +1 well asked.  Just enough info to get some good looking answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I think you want is to use your custom `Application` as the main `Application`.

So you dont add a new `<application>` but just specify its name to the main `<application>`(you need to specify its full package).

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name:"com.mypackage.MyApp"> <!-- Added the android:name -->
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Result" android:label="@string/app_name">        </activity>
</application>
```

See info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm)

Answer (score 21):

According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filec) manifest file with only **one** application element is valid.

> Only the <manifest> and <application> elements are required, **they each**
>   must be present and **can occur only once**.

Answer (score 0):

Only the 'manifest' and 'application' elements are required, they each must be present and can occur only once. Most of the others can occur many times or not at all — although at least some of them must be present for the manifest to accomplish anything meaningful.