# How to write a Flutter (Android) plugin that uses a custom application?

Tags: android, flutter, stetho

I'm trying to write a plugin for stetho, following [these steps](https://github.com/facebook/stetho).

It requires some initialization in onCreate method of a custom application.

```js
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
  }
}
```

and making an entry for the same application in AndroidManifest.xml.

```html
<manifest
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        ...>
        <application
                android:name="MyApplication"
                ...>
         </application>
</manifest>
```

But I get an error while trying `flutter run` for the flutter app that depends on this plugin -

```js
D:\Dev\Repo\flutter_test\myapp\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:16:9-57 Error:
        Attribute application@name value=(io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication) from AndroidManifest.xml:16:9-57
        is also present at [:stetho] AndroidManifest.xml:7:18-76 value=(com.vilokanlabs.stetho.stetho.MyApplication).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:name"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:15:5-38:19 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@name value=(io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication) from AndroidManifest.xml:16:9-57
        is also present at [:stetho] AndroidManifest.xml:7:18-76 value=(com.vilokanlabs.stetho.stetho.MyApplication).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:name"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:15:5-38:19 to override.
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that **only one application node is allowed** in Android. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7510697/9404410) and documented [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filec).

[*tool:replace*](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html) could also be a solution as suggested by @sagar-chavada, but it's not working. Somehow, app's manifest is considered/parsed later than the plugin's manifest, so *tool:replace* has effect if used in application's manifest (which is of no use) but has no effect if used in plugin's manifest (& an error is thrown).

So far, the **only solution** that worked for me is [**extending the Flutter's application class**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19002222/9404410) in the plugin -

```js
public class MyApplication extends FlutterApplication {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
    }
```

and **updating the app's manifest file to use this new sub-class** -

```html
<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->

    <application
        android:name="com.vilokanlabs.stetho.stetho.MyApplication"
        android:label="myapp"
        ...
```

As it turns out, comment here suggests the same.
Maybe not a very good solution for a plugin (will fail once there are two competing plugins) but it works!

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    **xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"**
    >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        **tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme,android:name"**
        >
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, didn't know about tools:replace. But in my case it's not helping. If I use it in the manifest of my plugin, then I get an error (it seems application manifest is parsed after the plugin manifest). And if I use it in the manifest of my application, then it's no use; plugin's application is never initialized. For now I'm directly replacing the application name in my original manifest file. Thanks again!